# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: blog.apps.BlogConfig.default_auto_field 'db.models.BigAutoField' that could not be imported

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following the Django project  and I'm into creating class models for my database section for those who know, and my system can't seem to runserver anymore, i'm encountering the following error:

Django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: blog.apps.BlogConfig.default_auto_field refers to the module 'db.models.BigAutoField' that could not be imported.

Initially, I thought it was my Django version, but I pip freeze and saw version 4.0.4

Model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    post_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

App.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'blog'
```

Comment: can you update your question with `apps.py`

Comment: Yes please, just did.

Comment: You must use the complete path `default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
`

Comment: Oh mehn - That Worked! Thanks!!